# tcolorbox: Can one store the parts of a breakable tcolorbox for later use?

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to delay the output of some parts of a breakable tcolorbox (I want to use them in a "notes column" and try to implement a way to split them if they get too long for a page). Has someone an idea how I could e.g. store the four parts of the following tcolorbox and then output them on a 2x2 grid on one page in the order 3,2,1,4?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
title=breakable,
watermark text=\arabic{tcbbreakpart},
enhanced jigsaw,
text width=4cm,
breakable,
break at=5cm/5cm/5cm/8cm]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) I think that is a good question. I had the same thing in mind for quite a long time. I even have a name for a library providing that feature (the `magazine` library), but I had no time yet to follow that thought. Maybe, someone has a clever idea to answer this question more easily.

Comment: I've wrote something similar, but not really the same, only for two parts, but it uses breakable `tcolorbox`es: the `jumplines` package. I thought about extending it, but I had no time so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER (needs `tcolorbox` version `3.70 (2015/07/16)` or newer:**

Starting from version `3.70 (2015/07/16)`, the `tcolorbox` package provides a new `magazine` library. The main purpose of this library is to store a tcolorbox into an array of box registers for later usage.

The `store to box array` option stores all parts of a break sequence of a tcolorbox into a box array. This is a sequence of `box registers` which can be inserted later with `\useboxarray{1}`, `\useboxarray{2}`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many,magazine]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  title=breakable,
  height fixed for=first and middle,
  watermark text=\arabic{tcbbreakpart},
  enhanced jigsaw,
  text width=4cm,
  breakable,
  break at=5cm/5cm/5cm/8cm,
  reset and store to box array
  ]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\tabcolsep=1pt\relax
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\useboxarray{3} & \useboxarray{2}\\
\useboxarray{1} & \useboxarray{4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLD ANSWER (useful for `tcolorbox` versions before `3.70`):**

*This was the base for the `magazine` library.*

The core of the solution is to capture the broken box parts into boxes automatically. Therefore, a series of boxes is needed, called a *box set* in the following. A `default` box set is created by the following code, but there could be more than one box set.

The capture operation is done using the new `store to box set` options. All box parts are appended to an existing box set. To clear the set from possible previous storage operation `reset box set` is used.

After saving, the boxes from the box set can be addressed as `\tcbuseboxset{1}`, `\tcbuseboxset{2}`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\def\newtcbboxset#1{%
  \global\csdef{tcb@boxset@#1@size}{0}%
  \global\csdef{tcb@boxset@#1@allocated}{0}%
}

\newtcbboxset{default}

\def\tcbstoretoboxset#1{%
  \tcbletboxsetsize[#1]\tcb@boxset@size%
  \numdef\tcb@boxset@size{\tcb@boxset@size+1}%
  \global\cslet{tcb@boxset@#1@size}{\tcb@boxset@size}%
  \letcs\tcb@boxset@allocated{tcb@boxset@#1@allocated}%
  \ifnum\tcb@boxset@allocated<\tcb@boxset@size\relax%
    \newbox\tcb@boxset@box\csxdef{tcb@boxset@#1@\tcb@boxset@size @box}{\the\tcb@boxset@box}%
    \global\cslet{tcb@boxset@#1@allocated}{\tcb@boxset@size}%
  \else%
    \letcs\tcb@boxset@box{tcb@boxset@#1@\tcb@boxset@size @box}%
  \fi%
  \edef\reserved@a{%
    \endgroup
    \global\setbox\tcb@boxset@box\hbox{%
      \begingroup\aftergroup}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
    \@endpefalse
    \color@setgroup
      \ignorespaces}

\def\endtcbstoretoboxset{\unskip\color@endgroup}

\def\tcb@storetoboxset@begin#1#2[#3]{\begin{tcbstoretoboxset}{#1}}
\def\tcb@storetoboxset@end{\end{tcbstoretoboxset}}

\tcbset{
  store to box set/.code={%
    \def\kvtcb@float{S}\def\tcb@float@env@begin{\tcb@storetoboxset@begin{#1}}\def\tcb@float@env@end{\tcb@storetoboxset@end}},
  store to box set/.default=default,
  reset box set/.code={\tcbresetboxset[#1]},
  reset box set/.default=default,
  do not store to box set/.style={nofloat},
}

\newrobustcmd*{\tcbletboxsetsize}[2][default]{%
  \letcs#2{tcb@boxset@#1@size}%
  \ifdef{#2}{}{%
    \tcb@error{undefined box set '#1'}%
    {You have to say \string\newtcbboxset{#1}, before '#1' can be used as box set.}%
  }%
}

\newrobustcmd*{\tcbresetboxset}[1][default]{%
  \tcbletboxsetsize[#1]\tcb@boxset@size%
  \global\csdef{tcb@boxset@#1@size}{0}%
}

\newrobustcmd*{\tcbuseboxset}[2][default]{%
  \tcbletboxsetsize[#1]\tcb@boxset@size%
  \ifnum\numexpr#2>0\relax%
    \ifnum\numexpr#2>\tcb@boxset@size\relax%
    \else%
      \global\letcs\tcb@boxset@box{tcb@boxset@#1@#2@box}%
      \usebox{\tcb@boxset@box}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  title=breakable,
  height fixed for=first and middle,
  watermark text=\arabic{tcbbreakpart},
  enhanced jigsaw,
  text width=4cm,
  breakable,
  break at=5cm/5cm/5cm/8cm,
  reset box set,
  store to box set,
  ]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\tabcolsep=1pt\relax
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\tcbuseboxset{3} & \tcbuseboxset{2}\\
\tcbuseboxset{1} & \tcbuseboxset{4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that the boxes are saved with the `\global` modifier and will survive the current TeX group. This could cause memory problems if used extensively.

The current number of boxes stored inside the box set can be questioned by `\tcbletboxsetsize{\mysize}`. Afterwards, `\mysize` contains the current size.

Comment: It is pretty hard competing with the package developer, but I'll take credit for egging you on to provide an elegant solution.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry for that ;-) I was aware that I should find a hook to answer this question. As I wrote to Ulrike, I wanted to have such a thing for a long time. Funnily, I found the core of the the solution two or three days ago, but had no time to elaborate it properly for an answer. Your answer pushed me into stealing some time to do it ;-)

Comment: Yes, your comment to the OP on 8 June indicated you had something in mind.  It's a nice feature to add.  Best wishes.

Comment: This works very fine (and also if one doesn't break the box manually).

Comment: Could the unbroken box be stored in the same run too (to get the size)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You mean a broken box plus a not broken box to compare the sizes? No, I don't think so, because the algorithm either breaks the box or not.

Comment: No, I don't need to compare the sizes. But I would like to be able to choose between "break the box or not" depending on the size of the box and the current position on the page. Can the box store the unbroken size to the aux-file? (It doesn't need to be exact).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The `\tcb@split@start` could be hacked for such a task with some id for the aux-file. But, if you know the available space, you could do a `break at=SPACE/../..`. With the new `\tcbletboxsetsize` you would know, if there really is a break or not.

Comment: The main problem is the "fuzzy" part: If the box is e.g. only 1cm to long I would prefer it to stick in the bottom margin instead of breaking it. But I think I can get a rough estimation by adding up the values of the parts and store this sum.  Or I could make a first "unbroken" compilation. I will have to think about it.

Answer (score 7):

Here, I set the broken `\tcolorbox` into a `\vbox`.  THat has the effect of leaving it as one vertical box, but it places the sectioning numbers properly (if you use an `\hbox`, you only get a large page "1").  Then, I `\clipbox` the saved page at regular intervals.

I first clipped 3pt off the bottom and 1pt off the top of the saved `\vbox` (i.e., blank space, maybe a `tcolorbox` setting).  Then, the vertical clip interval was 5pt less than the nominal 5cm height (I don't know why) and, being a `\vbox`, I had to trim from the right hand margin as well, in this case, 32pt less than `\textwidth-4cm`, to allow for the blank border on the sides.

I used `stackengine` to save the clips into boxes, but a simple `\savebox` `\usebox` would be equally suitable.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{trimclip,stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsavebox\breakbox
\newlength\cliptop
\newlength\clipbot
\begin{document}

\setbox0=\vbox{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
title=breakable,
watermark text=\arabic{tcbbreakpart},
enhanced jigsaw,
text width=4cm,
breakable,
break at=5cm/5cm/5cm/8cm]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}%
}
\savebox\breakbox{\clipbox{0pt 3pt 0pt 1pt}{\box0}}
\edef\dellength{\dimexpr5cm-5pt}
\def\rightclip{\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm-32pt}
%#1
\setlength\cliptop{0pt}
\setlength\clipbot{\dimexpr\ht\breakbox-\dellength\relax}
\savestack{\BoxA}{\clipbox{0pt {\clipbot} {\rightclip} {\cliptop}}{\usebox{\breakbox}}}
%#2
\addtolength\cliptop{\dellength}
\addtolength\clipbot{-\dellength}
\savestack{\BoxB}{\clipbox{0pt {\clipbot} {\rightclip} {\cliptop}}{\usebox{\breakbox}}}
%#3
\addtolength\cliptop{\dellength}
\addtolength\clipbot{-\dellength}
\savestack{\BoxC}{\clipbox{0pt {\clipbot} {\rightclip} {\cliptop}}{\usebox{\breakbox}}}
%#4
\addtolength\cliptop{\dellength}
\addtolength\clipbot{-\dellength}
\ifdim\clipbot<0pt\relax\setlength\clipbot{0pt}\fi
\savestack{\BoxD}{\clipbox{0pt {\clipbot} {\rightclip} {\cliptop}}{\usebox{\breakbox}}}
%
\tabcolsep=1pt\relax
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\BoxC & \BoxB\\
\BoxA & \BoxD
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]