# How to make a twocolumn breakable colored environment in book template

Tags: two-column, tcolorbox, mdframed

I'm trying to create a twocolumn breakable colored environment in tufte book template but using mdframed and tcolorbox wasn't useful.the error is : multicolumn does not make  sense in a box!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%------------------------------
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,
                  enhanced,
                  %%frame hidden,
                  interior hidden,
                  boxsep=0pt,
                  left=0pt,
                  right=0pt,
                  top=2pt,
                  ]%%
\twocolumn  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please Have a see on : http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 8):

`tcolorbox` can be used inside a `multicols` environment and boxes will break accordingly. But a `multicol` environment can only be used inside `non breakable` tcolorboxes.

But with `magazine` and `raster` libraries help it's possible to do something which looks like a `multicol environment inside a breakable tcolorbox`.

`magazine` library provides tools to store fragments of broken tcolorboxes inside an array. Later on these fragments can be inserted in our text as needed, even in different order. (See `magazine` origin: [tcolorbox: Can one store the parts of a breakable tcolorbox for later use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249207/tcolorbox-can-one-store-the-parts-of-a-breakable-tcolorbox-for-later-use/254564#254564))

Once we have all fragments, we can use a `tcboxedraster` or `tcboxeditemize` to compose all fragment like a boxed multicolumn.

This process is not automatic, first we should decide how large are initial fragments, and we have to know how many fragments has been produced because we have to manually type each one inside the raster. Not easy but possible.

A little example:

Some text: `\lipsum[1-8]` is broken in `.93\textheight X .42\textwidth` fragments and they are stored into a `default` array of `blanker` boxes:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[blanker, 
width=.42\textwidth,
breakable,
break at=.93\textheight,
%break at=.93\textheight/.93\textheight/.4\textheight,
reset box array,
store to box array,]
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

This text is only processed and stored, it's not printed at all.

Later on these fragments (3 in this case, although `\boxarraygetsize{\mysize}` will store the fragments number in `\mysize`) can be printed inside a `raster` or a `tcboxeditemize` like in this case.

```
\begin{tcboxeditemize}[%
    blanker, 
    raster columns=2, 
    sharp corners, 
    halign=center, 
    raster valign=top]{%
    breakable, 
    colback=yellow!20, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large, 
    colframe=red!80!yellow,
    title=Breakable twocolumn tcolorbox, 
    title after break= Second and last part,
    }
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{1}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{2}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{3}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{4}
\end{tcboxeditemize}
```

`\consumeboxarray{1}` uses and deletes the first fragment. As we have only three fragments, the reference to the fourth one is ignored without disturbing the work.

The result looks like:

[image]

If you prefer to better balance the second page, it's possible to do it but we have to manually set all fragments length. As an example:

```
break at=.93\textheight/.93\textheight/.4\textheight,
```

will force two breaks after `.93\textheight` lengths and all other ones will have `.4\textheight` length. With this numbers the result is:

[image]

And this is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[blanker, 
width=.42\textwidth,
breakable,
break at=.93\textheight,
%break at=.93\textheight/.93\textheight/.4\textheight,
reset box array,
store to box array,]
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcboxeditemize}[%
    blanker, 
    raster columns=2, 
    sharp corners, 
    halign=center, 
    raster valign=top]{%
    breakable, 
    colback=yellow!20, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large, 
    colframe=red!80!yellow,
    title=Breakable twocolumn tcolorbox, 
    title after break= Second and last part,
    }
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{1}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{2}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{3}
\tcbitem\consumeboxarray{4}
\end{tcboxeditemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`\twocolumn` inside a box doesn't make sense. But outside it works fine with tcolorbox. You can also use multicols inside a tcolorbox but only if this is not  breakable. If you want a frame around both columns of two column document you should draw it with other means, e.g. as background image with eso-pic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%%------------------------------
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth, %\linewidth, not \textwidth!
                  enhanced,
                  breakable
                  ]%%
 \lipsum[1-10]
\end{tcolorbox}

\onecolumn
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,
                  enhanced,
                  colback=blue!20!white
                  %breakable %won't work
                  ]%%
 \begin{multicols}{2}                  
 \lipsum[1-2]
 \end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach but your codes make tcolorbox twocolumned,while I'm looking for a twocolumned text in fullwidth tcolorbox.

Comment: Well the second example (with the blue background) shows a twocolumn text in a fullwidth tcolorbox.

Comment: Thank you again for your kind response but according to your codes,breakable won't work here, while a breakable environment is needed.