# Multicolumns inside tcolorbox breakable box

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to put a long text of two columns in a tcolorbox box with  breakable option. The text comes out of the box, and LaTeX does not produce a page break!

This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

The result :

[image]

Any advice ? Thank you

Comment: `multicols` inside `tcolorbox` is basically not possible (or very difficult, as far as I know, but the other way round works)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340191/how-to-make-a-twocolumn-breakable-colored-environment-in-book-template/355586#355586

Comment: Thank you Christian Hupfer and Ignasi. In the related link the title appears in all pages and  the lower part of the box  is not broken. tcolorbox is incompatible with multicol as I know. Another solution ?

Comment: @Haouam: You can as well claim that `multicol` is not compatible to `tcolorbox`. Page breaking etc. is a difficult issue

Comment: No solution then ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't nothing more than I copied the macros from OPmac `\begmulti`...`\endmulti` which implement multicolumn typesetting in plain TeX. And it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\newdimen\colsep \colsep=2em
\newcount\mullines
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\corrsize #1{%% #1 := #1 + \splittopskip - \topskip
   \advance #1 by \splittopskip \advance #1 by-\topskip
}
\def\begmulti #1 {\par\bgroup\penalty0 \def\Ncols{#1}
   \setbox6=\vbox\bgroup\penalty0
   %% \hsize := Sirka sloupce = (\hsize+\colsep) / n - \colsep
   \advance\hsize by\colsep
   \divide\hsize by\Ncols  \advance\hsize by-\colsep
   \mullines=0
   \def\par{\ifhmode\endgraf\global\advance\mullines by\prevgraf\fi}%
}
\def\endmulti{\vskip-\prevdepth\vfil
   \expandafter\egroup\expandafter\baselineskip\the\baselineskip\relax 
   \dimen0=.8\maxdimen \tmpnum=\dimen0 \divide\tmpnum by\baselineskip 
   \splittopskip=\baselineskip
   \setbox1=\vsplit6 to0pt
   %% \dimen1 := the free space on the page
   \vsize=.95\vsize
   \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen \dimen1=\vsize \corrsize{\dimen1}
   \else \dimen1=\pagegoal \advance\dimen1 by-\pagetotal \fi
   \ifdim \dimen1<2\baselineskip
     \vfil\break \dimen1=\vsize \corrsize{\dimen1} \fi
   \ifnum\mullines<\tmpnum \dimen0=\ht6 \else \dimen0=.8\maxdimen \fi
   \divide\dimen0 by\Ncols \relax
   %% split the material to more pages?
   \ifdim \dimen0>\dimen1 \splitpart
   \else \balancecolumns \fi  % only balancing
   \egroup
}
\def\makecolumns{\bgroup % full page, destination height: \dimen1
   \vbadness=20000 \setbox1=\hbox{}\tmpnum=0
   \loop \ifnum\Ncols>\tmpnum
      \advance\tmpnum by1
      \setbox1=\hbox{\unhbox1 \vsplit6 to\dimen1 \hss}
   \repeat
   \hbox{}\nobreak\vskip-\splittopskip \nointerlineskip
   \null\nobreak\medskip\hbox to\hsize{\unhbox1\unskip}
   \dimen0=\dimen1 \divide\dimen0 by\baselineskip \multiply\dimen0 by\Ncols
   \global\advance\mullines by-\dimen0
   \egroup
}
\def\splitpart{%
   \makecolumns % full page
   \vskip 0pt plus 1fil minus\baselineskip \break
   \ifnum\mullines<\tmpnum \dimen0=\ht6 \else \dimen0=.8\maxdimen \fi
   \divide\dimen0 by\Ncols \relax
   \ifx\balancecolumns\flushcolumns \advance\dimen0 by-.5\vsize \fi
   \dimen1=\vsize \corrsize{\dimen1}\dimen2=\dimen1
   \advance\dimen2 by-\Ncols\baselineskip
   %% split the material to more pages?
   \ifvoid6 \else
      \ifdim \dimen0>\dimen2 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \splitpart
      \else \balancecolumns % last balancing
   \fi \fi
}
\def\balancecolumns{\bgroup \setbox7=\copy6 % destination height: \dimen0
   \ifdim\dimen0>\baselineskip \else \dimen0=\baselineskip \fi
   \vbadness=20000
   \def\tmp{%
      \setbox1=\hbox{}\tmpnum=0
      \loop \ifnum\Ncols>\tmpnum
         \advance\tmpnum by1
         \setbox1=\hbox{\unhbox1
              \ifvoid6 \hbox to\wd6{\hss}\else \vsplit6 to\dimen0 \fi\hss}
      \repeat
   \ifvoid6 \else
      \advance \dimen0 by.2\baselineskip
      \setbox6=\copy7
      \expandafter \tmp \fi}\tmp
   \hbox{}\nobreak\vskip-\splittopskip \nointerlineskip
   \null\nobreak\medskip\hbox to\hsize{\unhbox1\unskip}%
   \egroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\begmulti 2
\lipsum[1-20]
%\end{multicols}
\endmulti
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Is there a way for the `begmulti` environment not to start on a newpage?

Comment: It works in middle of the page too (in plain TeX).

Comment: As "mac" says, if we add for exemple "Hello" between `\begin{document}` and `\begin{tcolorbox}` the tcolorbox begins in a new page. You also need to add the `\end{document}` in the code (because obviously the compilation gives `! Emergency stop.` without it).