# Twocolumn output in tcolorbox Number list not breakable

Tags: tcolorbox, enumitem

I get below coding from texstackexchange Answers part, trying `twocolumn` in breakable `tcolorbox` environment, problem is that `enumerate` and `itemize` not worked means that not balanced two columns, please help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\colsep \colsep=2em
\newcount\mullines
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\corrsize #1{%% #1 := #1 + \splittopskip - \topskip
   \advance #1 by \splittopskip \advance #1 by-\topskip
}
\def\begmulti #1 {\par\bgroup\penalty0 \def\Ncols{#1}
   \setbox6=\vbox\bgroup\penalty0
   %% \hsize := Sirka sloupce = (\hsize+\colsep) / n - \colsep
   \advance\hsize by\colsep
   \divide\hsize by\Ncols  \advance\hsize by-\colsep
   \mullines=0
   \def\par{\ifhmode\endgraf\global\advance\mullines by\prevgraf\fi}%
}
\def\endmulti{\vskip-\prevdepth\vfil
   \expandafter\egroup\expandafter\baselineskip\the\baselineskip\relax
   \dimen0=.8\maxdimen \tmpnum=\dimen0 \divide\tmpnum by\baselineskip
   \splittopskip=\baselineskip
   \setbox1=\vsplit6 to0pt
   %% \dimen1 := the free space on the page
   \vsize=.95\vsize
   \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen \dimen1=\vsize \corrsize{\dimen1}
   \else \dimen1=\pagegoal \advance\dimen1 by-\pagetotal \fi
   \ifdim \dimen1<2\baselineskip
     \vfil\break \dimen1=\vsize \corrsize{\dimen1} \fi
   \ifnum\mullines<\tmpnum \dimen0=\ht6 \else \dimen0=.8\maxdimen \fi
   \divide\dimen0 by\Ncols \relax
   %% split the material to more pages?
   \ifdim \dimen0>\dimen1 \splitpart
   \else \balancecolumns \fi  % only balancing
   \egroup
}
\def\makecolumns{\bgroup % full page, destination height: \dimen1
   \vbadness=20000 \setbox1=\hbox{}\tmpnum=0
   \loop \ifnum\Ncols>\tmpnum
      \advance\tmpnum by1
      \setbox1=\hbox{\unhbox1 \vsplit6 to\dimen1 \hss}
   \repeat
   \hbox{}\nobreak\vskip-\splittopskip \nointerlineskip
   \null\nobreak\medskip\hbox to\hsize{\unhbox1\unskip}
   \dimen0=\dimen1 \divide\dimen0 by\baselineskip \multiply\dimen0 by\Ncols
   \global\advance\mullines by-\dimen0
   \egroup
}
\def\splitpart{%
   \makecolumns % full page
   \vskip 0pt plus 1fil minus\baselineskip \break
   \ifnum\mullines<\tmpnum \dimen0=\ht6 \else \dimen0=.8\maxdimen \fi
   \divide\dimen0 by\Ncols \relax
   \ifx\balancecolumns\flushcolumns \advance\dimen0 by-.5\vsize \fi
   \dimen1=\vsize \corrsize{\dimen1}\dimen2=\dimen1
   \advance\dimen2 by-\Ncols\baselineskip
   %% split the material to more pages?
   \ifvoid6 \else
      \ifdim \dimen0>\dimen2 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \splitpart
      \else \balancecolumns % last balancing
   \fi \fi
}
\def\balancecolumns{\bgroup \setbox7=\copy6 % destination height: \dimen0
   \ifdim\dimen0>\baselineskip \else \dimen0=\baselineskip \fi
   \vbadness=20000
   \def\tmp{%
      \setbox1=\hbox{}\tmpnum=0
      \loop \ifnum\Ncols>\tmpnum
         \advance\tmpnum by1
         \setbox1=\hbox{\unhbox1
              \ifvoid6 \hbox to\wd6{\hss}\else \vsplit6 to\dimen0 \fi\hss}
      \repeat
   \ifvoid6 \else
      \advance \dimen0 by.2\baselineskip
      \setbox6=\copy7
      \expandafter \tmp \fi}\tmp
   \hbox{}\nobreak\vskip-\splittopskip \nointerlineskip
   \null\nobreak\medskip\hbox to\hsize{\unhbox1\unskip}%
   \egroup
}

\newenvironment{myboxtype1}[1][]
{\begin{myBoxTypeA*}[#1]\noindent\ignorespaces\begmulti 2}
{\endmulti\end{myBoxTypeA*}}

\newtcolorbox{myBoxTypeA*}[1][]{%
enhanced,
breakable,
arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0.5bp,boxsep=0pt,top=14pt,left=12pt,right=12pt,bottom=10.3pt,middle=0pt,
toptitle=6pt,bottomtitle=0pt,
%colback=boxbgndonecolor, colbacktitle=boxbgndonecolor,colframe=boxruleonecolor,
coltitle=black, titlerule=0pt,titlerule style={blue,line width=0pt},
attach boxed title to top left,
title={{#1}},
fonttitle=\color{white},
pad at break=12pt,bottomrule at break=0pt,toprule at break=0pt,grow to right by = 4pc, toggle enlargement
}%


\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{myboxtype1}[Box Title]
The IFRSs does not further clarify who must prepare general purpose financial reports. In jurisdictions adopting IFRS, legislation and other regulatory requirements usually require general purpose financial reports from entities that have issued debt or equity securities traded in a public market. The IASB does not, however, limit general purpose financial reporting to these entities. In this regard, the \textit{Conceptual Framework} indicates that a reporting entity can be any entity that has existing and potential investors, lenders and other creditors who must rely on general purpose financial reports for much of the information they need to make decisions about providing resources to the entity.
\end{myboxtype1}

\begin{myboxtype1}[Box Title]
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\begin{enumerate}
\item  they have public accountability (as defined in AASB 1053, Appendix A and B); and
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\end{enumerate}
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\end{myboxtype1}

\begin{myboxtype1}[Box Title]
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
They are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\begin{itemize}
\item  they have public accountability (as defined in AASB 1053, Appendix A and B); and
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\item  they are required by legislation to comply with Australian Accounting Standards.
\end{itemize}
\end{myboxtype1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen @Ignasi answer to this question [How to make a twocolumn breakable colored environment in book template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340191/how-to-make-a-twocolumn-breakable-colored-environment-in-book-template/355586)

Comment: Yes, above mentioned solution not suitable for my case.

Comment: Reproducible with only `\begmulti 2 <enumerate env> \endmulti` so the cause is most likely in `\begmulti` and `\endmulti` but not `tcolorbox`. It seems adding `\linewidth=\hsize` right after `\divide\hsize by\Ncols  \advance\hsize by-\colsep` in `\begmulti` works. Also since LaTeX 2021 June, now `\par` contains code for paragraph hooks, hence redefining `\par` isn't not a good idea anymore.