# `tcolorbox` collides with `multitoc`

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to put the `\tableofcontents` in a `tcolorbox`. When the `tableofcontents` is big enough, the box needs to break into two boxes. Without using package `multitoc`，the box breaks very well. While I add package `multitoc` to split the `\tableofcontents` into two column, the box can't break. An `mwe` and the output is like the following:

```tex
\documentclass[a7paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}%two columns of tableofcontents

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
  \tableofcontents
\end{tcolorbox}

\foreach \x in {1,...,60}{
  \section{foo}
    bar
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It's not possible to use `multicolum` text into breakable tcolorboxes. But you could try to use `magazine` librery like I propose [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355586/1952)

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a twocolumn breakable colored environment in book template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340191/how-to-make-a-twocolumn-breakable-colored-environment-in-book-template)

Comment: Actually it doesn't. But l found that this problem can not be solved!