# How can I make a fullwidth, breakable, two column environment that adjusts to margins in a two sided document. Example shown in figure below

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, two-column, examples

I'm writing a textbook, the format is twosided, different length in each margin. I want to include, however, worked out examples that ocuppy the full length of the page and in two column format as breakable environments. I have the understanding that this is not technically possible with tcolorbox since multicols inside tcolorbox are only possible with not breakable boxes and, as stated above, I want the environment to break.

[image: This is the environment I'm trying to achieve]

Any ideas? Thanks in advace.

Comment: Please provide some actionable information about your current document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ or, at the least, have given a try so far? The screenshot you posted creates the impression that (a) the main page layout is single-column with generous margins and (b) the "insert" is considerably wider (i.e., has narrower margins) and may come in either a single-column or a dual-column format. Is this impression correct? If not, please clarify your objectives. Please also clarify what you mean by "breakable environment"; in particular, what kind of break do you have in mind?

Comment: What you want, breakable boxes with multicolumns inside, is not possible with `tcolorbox` but if you can do it "by hand" [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355586/1952) can help

Comment: Thank you very much for you answers. I understand that this is very very hard if not impossible with actual packages. Thank you.