# tikzposter w/ page break

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, posters, tikzposter

Is it possible to have page break in a tex poster? I want to be able to add content spanning over multiple A0 posters. Another use would be to smoothly switch between poster sizes and booklet size so that I can easily print the content in both formats.

I started using [tikzposter](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter?lang=en), it describes the use of blocks in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikzposter/tikzposter.pdf) but if the content blows the boundary of the poster or block it is just truncated instead of creating a new page. I am open to be convinced to use something else than tikzposter.

Comment: maybe tcolobox is better suited, it has breakable boxes

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You could try the magazine library functionality of the tcolorbox package, like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441839

Comment: As it has been commented, `tcolorbox` offers some alternatives. Two of them `tcbraster` and `tcbposter` can be used to arrange several blocks over a page. `tcbraster` provides an easy way of aligning boxes inside a container box. The container can break between pages, but not inner boxes. On the other side, a `tcbposter` cannot break between pages but box contents can flow from one box to the other. In [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341/1952), among other solutions, you can find a [`tcbposter`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383347/1952) example.

Comment: To get multiple pages I think you must use something else than `tikzposter`, because a `tikzposter` is essentially one big `tikzpicture`.