# Defining an environment with markdown in a tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, catcodes, markdown

This works in Overleaf:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{markdown}

- Foo
- Bar

\end{markdown}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

But I can't define a new environment that does this with a single environment declaration (potentially with customizations to the tcolorbox), likely because even this doesn't work:

```
\newenvironment{notes}
  {\begin{markdown}}
  {\end{markdown}}
```

Is there a way define such an environment?

Comment: Look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533402/i-can-not-insert-markdown-environment-inside-personal-environment