# Side by side two columns text, with one column overflow

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, paracol

First of all, full disclosure: this is my first question on this site, so apologizes in advance.

**The Problem:** I would like to have a Latex command that accepts two documents and presents them in the following way. The two pieces of text should proceed side by side (in a two-column fashion) and then switch to one column again for whichever of the two comes out to be longer. *Note* that the two texts can be quite long and indeed span multiple pages. I have access to the two input documents, but I would like to modify them as little as possible, ideally the solution should not alter them at all.

**Incredibly realistic sketch of the solution.**

```
+-----------------+
|   Shared Title  |
+--------+--------+
|        |        |
|        |        |
|  Left  |  Right |
|  Text  |  Text  |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
+--------+--------+
    ~pagebreak~ 
+--------+--------+
|  Left  |  Right |
|  Text  |  Text  |
|        +--------|
|                 |
|  Trailing End   |
|  of Left Text   |
+--------+--------+
```

**What I got so far:** Thanks to questions such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441800/how-to-make-overlay-of-tcolorbox-span-over-multiple-pages) I was able to position the two texts side by side with the following code.

```
\newcommand{\sidebyside}[2]
{
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[blanker, breakable, width=\linewidth]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{tcolorbox}[blanker, breakable, width=\linewidth]
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{paracol}   
}
```

That I can later use in the document with a call such as:

```
\sidebyside{\input{left_text}}{\input{right_text}}
```

However with this setup whichever text comes up the longer will just keep going in its own column, while I would like it to break the two-column layout and proceed using the whole page. The idea I had was to modify the previous command to only print part of one of the two inputs to match its length to the shortest, like the following:

```
\newcommand{\sidebyside}[2]
{
    % Somehow measure which of #1 and #2 is longer
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[blanker, breakable, width=\linewidth]
        % Part of #1 with length matched to #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \switchcolumn
    \begin{tcolorbox}[blanker, breakable, width=\linewidth]
        % Part of #2 with length matched to #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{paracol}

    % Put here the remaining trail of either #1 and #2
}
```

The main sub-problems that I am facing are: *"How to measure which of the two inputs is longer?"*,  *"How to print only part of and input given its target length?"*.

The approach I depicted above may be doomed to fail, so I am open to any solution. I am using Overleaf as part of online collaboration.

Comment: getting wider at the end makes it quite a bit harder, especially if you want to do it in one pass. Also it's a lot harder if you want the width to change mid-paragraph, is that a requirement or can you finish the longer column at teh end of a paragraph?

Comment: I think finishing the longer column at the end of a paragraph works just fine. In case of a too-long-a-paragraph I can for example edit the longer text and insert manually a paragraph break  if needed.

Comment: If you only need this a few times, maybe splitting the larger input file manually and inserting the rest separately might be the easiest solution.